# JavaScript scrollIntoView function does not work - the page does not scroll into the element view

Tags: javascript, html, js-scrollintoview

I have a web page (using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP) and want to write some script to scroll my page to one of elements on it.

This worked well (when I clicked on the button, the page scrolled into view of `search_cont` element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <?php  include_once('head.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="scroll">Scroll</button>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var elmnt = document.getElementById("search_cont");
      elmnt.scrollIntoView();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this thing did not do anything:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <?php  include_once('head.php'); ?>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var elmnt = document.getElementById("search_cont");
      elmnt.scrollIntoView();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is, why this did not work, and how can I fix it? Or (alternative question), how can I scroll (right after the page is loaded) to some element on the page another way? - without using the (visible) button I have to click on.

I'll be very grateful for your responds.

Comment: it's because onload is not executed when DOM is loaded only when page finish loading whole page get downloaded by the browser, you can try DOMContentLoaded event instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: yes, this solved my problem, thanx

Answer (score 0):

See the console for Error, it seems like there isn't any DOM element with id `search_cont` found in your html. Refer to below example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("search_cont");
  elmnt.scrollIntoView();
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#search_cont {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="button">Click Here to go </button>
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries
</div>
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries
</div>
<hr>
<div id="search_cont">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries
</div>
<hr>
```